# Is it possible to extract the value of element in csproj file with dotnet CLI?

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, dotnet-cli

csproj file contains project properties which I'd like to use in CI/CD pipeline.

Is it possible to extract those values with dotnet cli (or some other standard tool) without parsing xml via some standalone script?

For example having the project:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Version>1.0.0</Version>
        <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    </PropertyGroup>
</<Project>
```

I need to resolve the value of `<Version>`.

It's also wroth noting that project may contain conditional elements, and ideally it would be nice to resolve properties in the context of predefined variables.

Answer (score 3):

MSBuild is very extensible.  You could use a target to write the version number to a file:

```xml
  <Target Name="WriteVersion" AfterTargets="Build">
    <WriteLinesToFile Lines="$(Version)"
                      File="$(IntermediateOutputPath)version.txt" />
  </Target>
```

That would write a version.txt file to a folder such as `obj/Debug/net5.0` (depending on the Configuration and TargetFramework).

Also be sure to check out https://msbuildlog.com/ for how to investigate / debug builds.